# R function displays object "obser" but won't write.CSV

Tags: r, export-to-csv

My code works and displays the correct values on screen for `print(obser)` but will not write the `.csv` and when I tried `str(obser)` it gave error `object 'obser' not found`. I have tried various online help and books and the function is correctly written.

If instead of running the function in the console in RStudio, I run line by line in the scrip screen will the csv then be created?

```
complete <- function(directory= "specdata", id = 1:332){ 

    # directory <- "specdata" 
    # id <- 1:332

    files_list <- list.files(path=directory,full.names=T)[id]
    NumOfFiles <- length(files_list) 
    obser <- data.frame() 
    indivFile <-data.frame()
    nobserv <- vector(mode= "integer", length = NumOfFiles) 

    for (i in 1:NumOfFiles){
        indivFile <- read.csv(files_list[i]) # read data file into df  inc NA's
        indivFile <- na.omit(indivFile) # removes NA prev file
        x <- nrow(indivFile[1]) 
        nobserv[i] <- x
    } 

    x_name <-"ID"
    y_name <-"nobs"
    obser <- data.frame(id, nobserv)

    return(obser) # object returned 
    print(obser)
    wd <- getwd()
    setwd(wd)
    write.csv(obser, file="Observations2.csv")
}
```

Comment: `setwd(wd <- getwd())` is not adding anything to the  code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and save the object returned from the function. Ergo:

```
output<-complete("specdata",id=1:332)
write.csv(output,"Observations2.csv",row.names=F)
```

Comment: tried it  thinking that  i had not run the function only defined it  but still not data file output

Comment: Sorry my mistake i   realize what the problem was... i first was indeed confusing function definition and running the function inside the scrip.

Comment: I also was trying to run the  code amonk  posted inside the closure bracket of the function  when i  placed them outside that bracket if functioned grea.